# C# What happens to memory after reallocating a class

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

It's easier to ask the question after showing an example...

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();

a.initializeData();
a = new MyClass();
```

After allocating space for a new MyClass, what happens to my previous allocation? Does the garbage collector automatically collect it because I know there's no delete in C#

I just want to make sure I'm not going to have any memory leaks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's called "creating an object", not "reallocating a class".

The entire idea of garbage collection is that you don't care what happens to objects on which you have no reference: you code as if there was infinite memory (within reason). The purpose of the garbage collector is not to free memory for you, [it is to simulate that there is an infinite amount of memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx).

It just so happens that in order to do this, the garbage collector might reclaim previously allocated memory on which you hold no reference from time to time; it might also reorganize the used memory to prevent fragmentation, and update all your references to point towards new memory locations. All of this is implementation details that you shouldn't be concerned with.

Of course, it's very interesting to learn how the GC works. :)

Answer (score 1):

The memory of the orphaned class will be deallocated from the garbage collector later.

See[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector is tracking references, as there is no reference to the first instances it will get collected later.

Comment: It would be better to phrase it that the garbage collector checks if there are references. This is done at the collection stage, the memory management system doesn't use reference counting to keep track of the references.

Comment: The .NET GC doesn't do reference counting.

Comment: The garbage collector doesn't really track references. It does a new check for references at each collection, it doesn't keep track of the references between the collections.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your program runs for long enough, and at some future point there's sufficient memory pressure or an explicit Garbage Collection occurs, then the first instance of `MyClass` will be collected (or will be put onto the finalizer queue, if it has a finalizer).

You shouldn't worry about *when* this will happen. The earliest it *could* happen is whilst `initializeData` is executing, after that method has stopped accessing any instance members via `this` (whether implicitly or explicitly).

---

Explicit Garbage Collection: you shouldn't ever need to perform this, outside of benchmarks or code demonstrating particular GC behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the garbage collector takes care of removing the unused object.

There is no guarantee when this happens, but as it's a short lived object it will usually happen at the next garbage collection.

If you need control over when the object is cleaned up (i.e. you use unmanaged resources in the class), you implement the `IDisposable` interface, and call the `Dispose` method to tell the object to clean up the resources.